# UDP - Datagram doesnt get received (Java)

Tags: java, networking, network-programming, udp, datagram

I have a program which sends a UDP `DatagramPackage` to the network. but the receiver computer doesn't get the package. note that the code is on both computers. the sender computer has the ip address of 10.0.0.3 and the receiver computer has the ip address of 10.0.0.6.

here is the code that runs on both computers.(the code is written in java 9)

```
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
  //field
    private static final int PORT = 60003;
    private static final String IP = "10.0.0.3";// or 10.0.0.6 for the receiver computer
  //methods

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        snd();
        rcv();


    }//main method

    public static void snd()
    {
        (new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                try(DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket())
                {
                    while(true)
                    {

                        String st = new Scanner(System.in).next();
                        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(st.getBytes(),st.getBytes().length ,InetAddress.getByName(IP), PORT);
                        s.send(packet);
                        Thread.yield(); 
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }//send method


    public static void rcv()
    {
        (new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                try(DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket(PORT))
                {
                    while(true)
                    {
                        byte[] b = new byte[1024];
                        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(b, b.length);
                        s.receive(packet);
                        for(int i = 0 ; i<packet.getLength() ; i++)
                        {
                            System.out.print((char) b[i]);
                        }
                    }

                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }//receive method
}//class Main
```

i can't find the problem since the code sent by the sender 10.0.0.3 gets received by the 10.0.0.3 but not by 10.0.0.6. i really appreciate it if someone could help

Comment: `private static final String IP = "10.0.0.3";`? You send only to that address.

Comment: it doesn't matter because the sender needs to send the packet with it's ip address which is 10.0.0.3 but the receiver isn't concerned with it

Comment: The "from" address will be filled automatically by the network stack. You need to tell the *destination* address to send the packet to.